# Getting the view frame size with respect to current Orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

If my app supports both Portrait & Landscape modes and I start my app in Landscape, I see that the UIViewController's view frame size is still dimensions for Portrait in viewDidAppear. (eg: 768x1024 instead of 748x1024)

I see the events coming in this order when I create and display the viewController:

```
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation // viewcontroller hasn't received rotate event yet
viewWillLayoutSubviews
viewDidLoad
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation // viewController now asked to change orientation
viewDidAppear
viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

Through these sequence of events, the view's frame size is still that of Portrait (although bounds is correct).

When could I expect the view's frame to be set correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the [**Cocoa Auto Layout system**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html) to define layout constraints for user interface elements. Constraints represent relationships between user interface elements such as “these views line up head to tail,” or “this button should move with this split view subview.” When laying out the user interface, a constraint satisfaction system arranges the elements in a way that most closely meets the constraints.

Watch [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202) for more details

Answer (score -1):

A Frame does not rotate, only bounds within a frame rotate when you rotate the device. Check using:

```
self.view.bounds
```

and you will see it changes when you rotate the device.

You need to read the View Programming guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW6

This is fundamental.

Comment: That's not true.
I have the same issue and both bounds and frame give me the same value




`NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));

NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));`

`{{0, 0}, {768, 975}}
{{0, 0}, {768, 975}}`

Furthermore there's nothing in the View programming guide that supports your claim.

Comment: @andrew I recommend you take the time to read the link I have in my answer.

Comment: I'd like a quote from there, validating your statement, please.

Here I'll go first:

 `The size of the bounds rectangle is coupled to the size of the frame rectangle, so that changes to one affect the other.`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/bounds

Comment: That one specifically was on a UIDeviceOrientationChanged notification.
P.S. In that particular case I have a tab bar, hence the smaller height.

Comment: Put your NSLog in  - (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {}. What do you get?

Comment: It gives me the same thing in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation

Comment: So then the issue must have to do with your tab bar setup. I need more details on this tab bar to help.

Comment: There's no issue...
I was just saying that you're wrong about bounds and frame sizes